# Git(hub): change branch?

Tags: git, github, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I've forked a repo on github and then made a few changes on master branch.
But I made a mistake, I had to work on a new branch not on the master one.

Can I change branch or should I fork the master again, then make the branch and apply the changes I made?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rename your local branch:

```
git branch -m master newbranch
```

Push it to your remote (let's say `myremote`):

```
git push myremote newbranch
```

Create a master branch from github's original remote (say `origin`):

```
git branch master origin/master
```

Forcefully push it:

```
git push myremote +master:master
```

This should do it.